# Ubuntu Disk Partition

Tags: partitioning

Well, i recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 in a HDD of 640 GB capacity. After the installation, I decided that i should partition my HDD so to have on the one partition the os and some other files (320 gb) and save to the other partition my video-edit works (320 gb). And I did so using the Ubuntu 14.04 live cd and gparted. I formatted the new disk part "with" ext4. But then something wird happened: While i am using ubuntu without any problem, i cannot edit the second partition, which means that i can't save or create something there! Ubuntu says that I am not the owner!! Why?? I need to solve this immediately!

***EDIT: Both of these two solutions below worked for me! However, faster way proved to be the one I have chosen!***

Comment: Is your partition automatically mounted somewhere? What does `mount` says about mounted partitions? If you can mount it, what's who's the owner of the mount point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type

```
 mount
```

in terminal and find the partition which you want to change ownership

my output looks like [image]

if I want to change ownership of partition **/dev/sd8** which is a ext4 partition and mounted on **/media/bibi/films**

you can also check ownership of mounted partitions with command

```
 ll /media/bibi
```

as you can see my films folder is owned by root

[image]

To change the ownership I have to run

```
sudo chown -R bibi:bibi /media/bibi/film
```

[image]

you have to **substitute bibi with your user name**

It is explained here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1137537

Comment: Thank you very much! I am new to Ubuntu, so I didn't know that! :D

Answer (score 0):

Because the partition was created outside your Ubuntu installation, it is owned by some other user, probably the super-user of the live cd. You can either reformat the partition inside Ubuntu and assign it to the current user or simply change read/write permissions so that the current user has access to that partition. This might also require giving the current user permissions to mount that partition.